# How to force Spring Scheduled run parallel execution of single method?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, parallel-processing, spring-scheduled

I'm trying to use `@Scheduled` method to process some regular work (every second). Body of this method can process during more than one second and I see that if this happens next execution is not started. Does Spring support it or I should change it to any other concurrent solution?

I have tried to change Scheduler to `ConcurrentTaskScheduler`, but looks like it helps only if we have few schedules methods.

```
@Service
public class MainService {
    @Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
    public void doSomething() {
       //some logic which can takes more than 1 second   
    }
}

@Configuration
public class SchedulingConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(
                Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100));
    }
}
```

Once the first execution is taking extra time the second execution will not be started. Otherwise, all works fine. How can I set up parallel execution of one scheduled method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce an async component so it does not take 1 second https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

```
@Service
public class MainService {

@Autowired
private SomethingService somethingService;

    @Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
    public void doSomething() {
       somethingService.doSomething();   
    }
}

//Introduce an async component so it does not take 1 second. runs doSomething() in a separate thread

@Component
public class SomethingService {

    @Async
    public void doSomething() {
       //some logic which can takes more than 1 second   
    }
}
```